API sync failed - transitioning to LOCAL_ONLY when removing public read/create auth rule from @model
I'm encountering an issue with AWS Amplify DataStore in my Android application. When I remove the { allow: public, operations: [read, create] } authorization rule from my User model, I receive the following error during the initial sync:
API sync failed - transitioning to LOCAL_ONLY.
W/amplify:aws-datastore(20148): DataStoreException{message=Initial sync during DataStore initialization failed., cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: IrRecoverableException{message=Empty response from AppSync., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=Report to AWS team.}, recoverySuggestion=There is a possibility that there is a bug if this error persists. Please take a look at
W/amplify:aws-datastore(20148): https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues to see if there are any existing issues that
W/amplify:aws-datastore(20148): match your scenario, and file an issue with the details of the bug if there isn't.}

### `User` Model Schema:
```graphql
type User @model
@auth(rules: [
  { allow: owner, ownerField: "userID", operations: [read, create, update, delete] }
]) {
  id: ID!
  userID: String!
  deletedAt: AWSDateTime
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  birthday: AWSDate!
  phone: AWSPhone!
}

Steps Taken:

Initially, my User model included the following auth rule: { allow: public, operations: [read, create] }, and everything worked fine.
I removed the { allow: public, operations: [read, create] } rule to restrict access only to the owner.
Upon removing this rule, the initial sync fails with the above error.

Question:

Why does the initial sync fail when I remove the { allow: public, operations: [read, create] } rule from my User model?
How can I restrict access to only the owner while ensuring the initial sync succeeds?

I've checked the AWS documentation and GitHub issues but couldn't find a solution that resolves this specific problem. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
